# I am wondering what it is called when an argument or description uses what the thing is not to expose a point or concept

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

This is useful when trying to expose on an abstract concept or something that is not a commonly understood. so contracting the difference between complimentary  phenomena that are defined. It directs or illuminates the listener or readers focus toward or in the direction of the concept of interest.

Comment: Please provide a specific example.

Comment: [Litotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes), perhaps?

Comment: This notion seems vaguely similar to some of the strategies used in education, where “scaffolding” is used not only to build vertically on a student’s prior knowledge, but also to connect horizontally with their prior knowledge to help them learn totally new concepts with both familiar examples and analogies, as well as with unfamiliar and thought-provoking **non-examples** and **discrepant analogies** /events/situations.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly old text, but from [Literary and Theological Review...](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=w3QXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA382&lpg=PA382&dq=%22definition%20by%20exclusion%22%20%22by%20contrast%22&source=bl&ots=M5g_24qZ_g&sig=6c32rVRUeTqXro3m0QgB3z2Tjbw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixltS3o7bKAhUETCYKHWmPB8YQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=%22definition%20by%20exclusion%22%20%22by%20contrast%22&f=false)

> *[This definition type] is of two kinds, **definition by exclusion,** and **definition by contrast.** Both may very well be employed together, for the contrast or direct opposite of an idea is, of course, excluded from the idea itself.*

Thus, *Whales are not fish* excludes "whales" from the category "fish". A more comprehensive *definition by contrast* might be, for example, [*A whale is a mammal, mainly because it nurses its young. Also because it has hair, lungs, and vestigal legs (modified flippers). Fish lay eggs, have scales, gills, and true fins.*](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080619065002AAI5Dtp)

Answer (score 0):

***Apophasis*** refers to knowledge (usually of God) obtained or stated through negation.

It is defined [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apophatic) as "knowledge, understanding, or description of God through negative statements about qualities and characteristics that God does not possess" (sense 2).

For example, "God is not located anywhere in space, god is not located anywhere in time, god is not biological."

But you can use it, more broadly, to mean any knowledge obtained or stated via negation.

For example, "Pepsi is not Coca Cola. Pepsi is not an animal. Pepsi is not my grandmother."

You may also be looking for ***negative definition*** or ***indirect definition***.